# Historical Data - Level II with Time and Sales Data

Tags: market-data, historical-data

I'd like to get historical data for level II (Time, BidPrice, BidSize, AskPrice, AskSize) and Time & Sales (Time, Price, Size) data  (with timestamp indeed) for machine learning purposes. I want this information for as long as possible and for some stocks.

If someone has collected the data and self-timestamped the data on receipt, then I would be ready to buy them their information if they are ready to sell it to me.

I've seen a similar [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/historical-level-2-data-market-depth), but it's a very long time ago, so I'd like to have some new answers to be in tune with today's reality.

How can I get that information?

### UPDATE

```
1- AKER (NASDAQ)
2- PHOTO (OTC)
3- HMNY (NASDAQ)
4- GERN (NASDAQ)
5- RNVA (OTC)
6- HEMP (OTC)
7- MJNA (OTC)
8- ZNGA (NASDAQ)
9- MARA (NASDAQ)
10- DCIX (NASDAQ)
```

I need the historical data for these actions for 1 to 2 years.

Comment: It seems you have two accounts, [please have them merged](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Also, I don't think one would be allowed by the exchanges to resell this data to you but I'm not very knowledgeable in this area.